# How to send button or list with whatsapp web js? list and button make chat unreplyable

Tags: node.js, list, button, whatsapp

I want to reply message with list or button. I don't have problem with sending text. But once a chat message asking a reply that using List or Button, that chat (either contact or group) won't receive any reply, even only text, and I have to reinstall whatsapp and clean refresh the chat history for the chat to replyable again.

on the code below, if I first chat the bot `!ping`, I got reply `pong`. then if I chat `!option`, there is no error and there is no reply. even the `console.log("After replying productsList");` is printed. then I try to chat `!ping` again, I got no reply but the `console.log('pong')` is printed

I already try to install this `npm i git+https://github.com/pedroslopez/whatsapp-web.js#fix-buttons-list` from this issue `https://github.com/pedroslopez/whatsapp-web.js/issues/1759` but the problem still occur.

```
import { commands } from "./handleMessage/command.js";
import wa_web from "whatsapp-web.js";
const { Client, LocalAuth, Buttons, List } = wa_web;
import qrcode from "qrcode-terminal";

const client = new Client({
  authStrategy: new LocalAuth(),
});

client.on("qr", (qr) => {
  qrcode.generate(qr, { small: true });
});

client.on("ready", async () => {
  console.log("Client is ready!");
});

client.on("message", async (msg) => {
  const contact = await msg.getContact();
    if (msg.body.charAt(0) === "!") {
      let cmd = msg.body.split(" ")[0];
      const command = commands[cmd];
      if (command) {
        await command(msg, client);
      } else {
        msg.reply("Perintah tidak ditemukan");
      }
    } else {
      let textReceived = msg.body;
      let text = `From: ${contact.name}\nNomor: ${contact.id.user}\nPesan: ${textReceived}\n`;
      client.sendMessage("9999myNumber@c.us", text);
    }
});

client.initialize();
```

```
import wa_web from "whatsapp-web.js";
const { Buttons, List } = wa_web;

export const commands = {
  "!ping": async (msg, client) => {
    console.log("pong");
    msg.reply("pong");
  },
  "!option": async (msg, client) => {
    console.log("Executing !option command"); // Add this line
    try {
      const productsList = new List(
        "Here's our list of products at 50% off",
        "View all products",
        [
          {
            title: "Products list",
            rows: [
              { id: "apple", title: "Apple" },
              { id: "mango", title: "Mango" },
              { id: "banana", title: "Banana" },
            ],
          },
        ],
        "Please select a product"
      );
      console.log("Before replying productsList");
      msg.reply(productsList);
      console.log("After replying productsList");
    } catch (error) {
      msg.reply(error);
      console.log(error);
    }
  },
};
```

is there any way to fix the unreplyable chat or the way to able send list and button?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.